# how to check two fields having same values in same table in laravel 5 with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5.1

I have to check the two fields having same values in same table in laravel 5. I am using Mongodb.

```
{
"id": "565d23ef5c2a4c9454355679",
"title": "Event1",
"summary": "test",
"total": NumberInt(87),
"remaining": NumberInt(87),
"status": "1"
}
```

I need to check "total" and "remaining" fields are same. How to write query in laravel 5.1. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you could take would be using the aggregation framework methods from the raw MongoDB collection object provided from the underlying driver. In the mongo shell, you would essentially run the following aggregation pipeline operation to compare the two fields and return the documents which satisfy that criteria:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "isMatch": { "$eq" : ["$total", "$remaining"]  }, // similar to "valueof(total) == valueof(remaining)"
            "id" : 1,
            "title" : 1,
            "summary" : 1,
            "total" : 1,
            "remaining" : 1,
            "status" : 1
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$match": { "isMatch": true  } // filter to get documents that only satisfy "valueof(total) == valueof(remaining)"      
    }
]);
```

Or using the **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** operator in the **[`find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)** query:

```
db.collection.find({ "$where" : "this.total == this.remaining" })
```

Thus in laravel, you can get the documents using **[raw expressions](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB#raw-expressions)** as follows

```
$result = DB::collection("collectionName") -> raw(function ($collection)
{
    return $collection->aggregate(array(
        array(
            "$project" => array(
                "id" => 1,
                "title" => 1,
                "summary" => 1,
                "total" => 1,
                "remaining" => 1,
                "status" => 1,
                "isMatch" => array(
                    "$eq" => array( "$total", "$remaining" )
                )                
            )
        ),
        array(
            "$match" => array(
                "isMatch" => true               
            )
        ) 
    ));
});
```

In the case of **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)**, you can inject the expressions directly into the query:

```
Model::whereRaw(array("$where" => "this.total == this.remaining"))->get();
```

Or using the raw expression on the internal MongoCollection object executed on the query builder. Note that using the **`raw()`** method requires using a cursor because it is a low-level call:

```
$result = Model::raw()->find(array("$where" => "this.total == this.remaining"));
```

Comment: $result = Event::whereRaw(array("where" => array('this.tickets', '=', 'this.remaining')))->get();
I used this query but i got empty result in laravel. 
Output:  Collection {#335 ▼
  #items: []
}

Comment: @Nimisha You are getting an empty result because the query is wrong; instead of `$result = Event::whereRaw(array("where" => array('this.tickets', '=', 'this.remaining')))->get();`, you should write `$result = Event::whereRaw(array("$where" => "this.tickets == this.remaining"))->get();` as structured in the answer, pay close attention to the array elements.

Comment: When i use this $result = Event::whereRaw(array("$where" => "this.tickets == this.remaining"))->get(); i got "Undefined variable: where" error.

Comment: I tried the query $result= Event::raw()->find(array('$where' => array('this.tickets == this.remaining'))); but it showed the result like:
MongoCursor {#325 ▼
  ns: "eventsflip.events"
  limit: 0
  batchSize: 0
  skip: 0
  flags: 0
  query: array:1 [▼
    "$where" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "this.tickets == this.remaining"
    ]
  ]
  fields: {#331}
  started_iterating: false
  dead: false
}
How can I get the data?

Comment: `find()` returns a [**cursor**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php) thus you need to iterate over it to get the data e.g you could do `foreach ($result as $doc) {
    // do something to each document
}` or `var_dump(iterator_to_array($result));`

Comment: $result = Event::whereRaw(array('$where' => "this.tickets == this.remaining"))->get();   got worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collectionname::whereRaw(array('$where' => "this.filed1 > this.field2"))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).